# How to return a value when you have KeyError Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to turn a python's keys into lists, however, some keys are empty and I get KeyError. To avoid the KeyError, I want it to return an empty string so I can easily append this to a dataframe.
Also, I want an efficient/better way to run the code below, since I am retrieving a large amount of information, and implementing this process manually is very time consuming.

My code:

```
ages= []
names = []

for i in range(len(test)):
    
    try:   
        age= test[i]["age"]
        ages.append(age)

    except KeyError:
        age= ""
        ages.append(age)

    try:
        name = test[i]["name"]
        names.append(name)
        
    
    except KeyError:
        name = ""
        names.append(name)
```

I have many other data points from this dict that I want to retrieve such as weight, height, etc. and doing a try/except for all them can be tedious for code. Is there an efficient way to recreate this code.

Comment: Just use `test[i].get(key, "")`, this returns an empty string if `key` isn't in the dictionary.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. God bless you mate!!!!

Comment: Do you know how I replicate this if I am scraping a website? For example I used ```Beautifulsoup.find("name")``` and it return nothing to me because it wasn't there. How I can I replicate this to return an empty string when there is nothing retrieved or found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main ways.

Let's assume you have the simplified dict:

```py
names = {123: 'Bob Roberts', 456: 'Alice Albertsons'}
```

And we're going to look up a name with ID `789`, and we want to get `John Doe` when `789` isn't found in the `names` dictionary.

**Method 1:** Use the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method, which accepts a default value:

```py
name_789 = names.get(789, 'John Doe')
```

**Method 2:** Use the [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method, which accepts a default value, and will also add that default as the new value in the `dict` if needed:

```py
name_789 = names.setdefault(789, 'John Doe')
```

**Method 3:** Create the dictionary as a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```py
names = collections.defaultdict((lambda: 'John Doe'), [
    (123, 'Bob Roberts'), (456, 'Alice Albertsons')
])

name_789 = names[789]
```

Note: Method 1 (`get`) is often really useful for nested dictionaries.

For example: `outer.get(outer_key, {}).get(middle_key, {}).get(inner_key)` will return `outer[outer_key][middle_key][inner_key]` if possible, or just `None` if any of the dicts needed are missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `get` method of dictionaries and also loop directly through your list:

```py
ages= []
names = []
for t in test:
    ages.append(t.get("age", "")
    names.append(t.get("name", "")
```

Comment: Do you know how I replicate this if I am scraping a website? For example I used Beautifulsoup.find("name") and it return nothing to me because it wasn't there. How I can I replicate this to return an empty string when there is nothing retrieved or found other than in a dict?

Comment: This is a different problem since in this case no error is raised (it just returns `None`). You could do sth like `n = Beautifulsoup.find("name")` then `if not n: n = ""`

Comment: But I'd have to do that to all the other elements I wish to retrieve such as age, weight, height... an if for all of them which will make the code long. Is there an efficient way that returns a default value similar to this `dict.get(key, default)` method in my case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. You could store your ages, weights, heights... in a dictionary with the same keys as your `test` elements then loop over your keys/values... I suggest your create a new question to explain the problem in details

Comment: OK I will create a new question, thank you anways

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) collection instead of a simple dictionary.

It creates a default value for a "missing" key.

Comment: Do you know how I replicate this if I am scraping a website? For example I used Beautifulsoup.find("name") and it return nothing to me because it wasn't there. How I can I replicate this to return an empty string when there is nothing retrieved or found other than in a dict?

Comment: You can initialize an empty `defaultdict` with your initializer function (for "missing" members). Your function should be `lambda x: ""` because you want to return an empty string. Then you can call `update` method for your `defaultdict` and then go over it as your regular dict.